# How to submit value of TextField without pressing the submit button

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

Is there an easy way to be able to get the text value for the TextField without it having to go through the onSubmit parameter? This is so that if the user taps away I could still fire the logic for the input.

```
onSubmitted: (value) {
    //useValue
  },
```

I have an idea to concatenate strings `onChanged:` but I guess what I am looking for is a combination of focus change (losing focus) and getting the value parameter passed somehow.

Comment: with `onChanged` you dont need to concatenate anything: the `String value` parameter passed to that callback contains the whole string entered in `TextField`

Comment: Let us say you are checking a OTP field, you can catch the event using onChanged event, by the way if the user has entered 4 characters, you can check that in the onChanged event with the length of the input value and then you can perform background operations and then proceed with the next page or action / While you are doing the background process you can show a loader on the screen on max stack position.

Comment: @pskink thanks for that. For some reason I thought the string got overwritten.